# Pyside getting a widget inside a QtabWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I have a QtabWidget and I made a ListWidget inside that tabwidget

```
self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
self.listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget(self.tabWidget)
```

Then I made a tab:

```
self.tab1 = QtGui.QWidget()
self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab1,"hi")
```

What I'm trying to do is get the listview for inside QTabWidget for tab1.

```
print self.tabWidget.currentWidget()
```

It prints out a pointer:
    PySide.QtGui.QWidget object at 0x0000000004EA84A4
I want the QListWidget so I can call functions like addItem etc.

Edit: I also have another question. I'm using Pyside and theres a function called retranslateUI and setupUI. I want to add a signal for my QTabWidget,

```
self.tabWidget.currentChanged.connect(self.showStreamList(self.tabWidget.tabText(self.tabWidget.currentIndex())))
```

but I'm not sure where to put it. I'm putting it in retranslateUI because thats there button.clicked.connects are but when I run the program, I think it executes this command first. The GUI doesn't even display. In general, where should I group these signals/event listeners?

Comment: You are setting the QTabWidget as the parent object of the QListWidget. The QTabWidget has no way of knowing who subclasses it. currentWidget() returns the widget currently active in the QTabWidget, which is tab1 if you don't add any other widget in the meantime. I think you're trying to achieve something different, which I can't see here. Please give more context of what you're trying to do. Do you want to add a QListWidget as a tab to the QTabWidget?

Comment: yes that is what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to have a user be able to add more tabs and every tab has a QListWidget but depending on the tab, I want to display different things inside the List. That means I have to get that specific widget for the tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your comment into account, you seem to want to dynamically add QListWidgets to a QTabWidget and want individual access to each QListWidget.

QTabWidget's addTab() method takes a QWidget and a string as its arguments. A QListWidget, as the name implies, is derived / subclassed from QWidget. Therefore, the `addTab()` method will accept a QListWidget, if you pass it one. So `self.tabWidget.addTab(self.listWidget,"hi")` should work just fine.

Next, accessing them. QTabWidget has a method to access any tab by its index, sensibly called `widget(index)`. Therefore, if you want to access the `n`-th widget, you can get it by calling `self.tabWidget.widget(n)`.

You could therefore get any list widget and do stuff with it:

```
lw = self.tabWidget.widget(0) # get the 0th widget
lw.addItem(...)
```

Comment: That works thanks! How would you get the current tab? I'm trying to get the name of the tab.

Comment: tabWidget.tabText(index) gets you the text for a tab and tabWidget.currentIndex() gets you the index of the currently active tab.